# kprobes not working in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-13.10, systemtap

I am trying to run one of the standard example scripts from Systemtap. 
The procmod_watcher.stp uses kprobes to watch fork, exec, etc.
But when I try to Run this script I get an error.

```
semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'kprobe' at /usr/share/systemtap/tapset/linux/nd_syscalls.stp:967:27
    source: probe nd_syscall.execve = kprobe.function("do_execve")
```

sure enough :`stap -L 'kprobe.function("do_execve")'` returns nothing.
How can this be?

I am using Ubuntu have followed the instructions in:
[Systemtap on Ubuntu @sourceware](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/SystemtapOnUbuntu)

I have also tried compiling my own kernel and making sure Kprobes, debug_info and all the other required items are enabled though config.
I get the same error.

I have tried the same script on fedora and it runs practically out of the box. But I only have a virtual machine with fedora on and would like to continue with ubuntu for a while.

What do I need to do to enable kprobes in systemtap on ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `kprobe.function` probes rely on systemtap reading the `System.map` file for lists of functions.  Run

```
stap -vv -L 'kprobe.function("do_execve")'
```

to see where stap is looking for that file; it's probably complaining about "Kernel symbol table ... unavailable".  Arrange to put a `System.map` symlink there, and stap should find it and the `do_execve` function within it.  We can extend stap's search path to find the file in its original location; pointers welcome.  Or if the problem is permissions,

```
sudo chmod a+r /boot/System.map*
```

This is to work around a misguided part of https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features - see also https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15172

Comment: This is exactly right, I get :
Kernel symbol table /lib/modules/3.11.0-15-generic/build/System.map unavailable, (No such file or directory)
Kernel symbol table /boot/System.map-3.11.0-15-generic unavailable, (Permission denied)
I'm checking how it goes with the revised permissions now.

Comment: yes, just the permissions change was sufficient to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @fche answer, SystemTap is looking for System.map in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/System.map`.

In Ubuntu, system.map is placed in `/boot/System.map-$(uname -r)`
so:

1. You need run stap as sudo (since only root has access to /boot or do some groups magic)
2. Create a soft link to System.map: `sudo ln -s /boot/System.map-$(uname -r) /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/System.map`

I would not recommend changing the read flag on the files in either location, security and all...